# How to add and relate a node within the parent nodes add form in Drupal

Tags: drupal, inline, editing, relate

I want to accomplish the following scenario in Drupal:

You have 2 content-types. Lets say, an application-form for a lisence, and a content-type for persons.

Then when you go to add a lisence in the "node/add" submission form in Drupal, i would like to add a relative number of persons that would be related to this lisence, and only this lisence. Say you would like to apply for a lisence, and relate 4 persons to this lisence, then insted of creating the lisence and then create the 4 persons and relate them to the lisence, i would like to do this "inline".

So when i add a lisence, there would be a way to add 1 or more persons that would relate to the lisence node. Is this possible, and if so how?

I have been looking at the node reference module, and that manages to reference a node to another, but not to add them inline with the other.

With the web-development framework Django, there is a way to this with something called "inline-editing", where you get the content-type fields inside another content-type creation form. There you bind them togheter with a ForeignKey.

Anybody know of something simular in Drupal, if not, is it another way to achive something simular, that would be as user-friendly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by inline, here.  Can you define?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked into this, and it doesnt seem to be possible. I have looked at the reference_create module, and searched and posted stuff on drupal.org, and nobody have a nice solution.

So what I just rebuilt the whole thing in Django in about 3 hours; so, tomorrow I will try to convince my employer to go the Django way!

Answer (score 2):

The [Popups: Add and Reference](http://drupal.org/project/popups_reference) module has recently been improved and I think it might do what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Node Relationship](http://drupal.org/project/noderelationships), it will add buttons for edit/view/add next to the node reference field and will pop up a modal. Make sure you check the module dependencies.